# Comparing Delegates in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to compare C# delegates for equality. I consider two delegates to be equal if they invoke the same method on the same instance of an object (or static) or if their method bodies have the exact same compiled IL. The code below includes the test cases I need the comparison to pass:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public delegate int Compare<Type>(Type left, Type right);
    public delegate int Compare<Left, Right>(Left left, Right right);

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Test 0 (false control)
            Action _0_1 = () => { };
            Action<int> _0_2 = (int i) => { Math.Sign(i); };
            Console.WriteLine("0:\t" + (Equate(_0_1, _0_2) == false));

            // Test 1s (same type delegates from static-method)
            Compare<int> _1s_1 = Test;
            Compare<int> _1s_2 = Test;
            Console.WriteLine("1s:\t" + Equate(_1s_1, _1s_2));

            // Test 1i (same type delegates from instance-method)
            Program _1i_0 = new Program();
            Compare<int> _1i_1 = _1i_0.Test3;
            Compare<int> _1i_2 = _1i_0.Test3;
            Console.WriteLine("1i:\t" + Equate(_1i_1, _1i_2));

            // Test 2s (same type delegates from same type static-delegates)
            Compare<int> _2s_1 = new Compare<int>(_1s_1);
            Compare<int> _2s_2 = new Compare<int>(_1s_2);
            Console.WriteLine("2s:\t" + Equate(_2s_1, _2s_2));

            // Test 2i (same type delegates from same type instance-delegates)
            Compare<int> _2i_1 = new Compare<int>(_1i_1);
            Compare<int> _2i_2 = new Compare<int>(_1i_2);
            Console.WriteLine("2i:\t" + Equate(_2i_1, _2i_2));

            // Test 3s (different type delegates from static-method)
            Compare<int> _3s_1 = Test;
            Compare<int, int> _3s_2 = Test;
            Console.WriteLine("3s:\t" + Equate(_3s_1, _3s_2));

            // Test 3i (different type delegates from instance-method)
            Program _3i_0 = new Program();
            Compare<int> _3i_1 = _3i_0.Test3;
            Compare<int, int> _3i_2 = _3i_0.Test3;
            Console.WriteLine("3i:\t" + Equate(_3i_1, _3i_2));

            // Test 4s (same type delegates from different type static-delegates)
            Compare<int> _4s_1 = new Compare<int>(_3s_1);
            Compare<int> _4s_2 = new Compare<int>(_3s_2);
            Console.WriteLine("4s:\t" + Equate(_4s_1, _4s_2));

            // Test 4i (same type delegates from different type instance-delegates)
            Compare<int> _4i_1 = new Compare<int>(_3i_1);
            Compare<int> _4i_2 = new Compare<int>(_3i_2);
            Console.WriteLine("4i:\t" + Equate(_4i_1, _4i_2));

            // Test 4s.1 (same type delegates from different type static-delegates)
            Compare<int, int> _4s_1_1 = new Compare<int, int>(_3s_1);
            Compare<int, int> _4s_1_2 = new Compare<int, int>(_3s_2);
            Console.WriteLine("4s.1:\t" + Equate(_4s_1_1, _4s_1_2));

            // Test 4i.1 (same type delegates from different type instance-delegates)
            Compare<int, int> _4i_1_1 = new Compare<int, int>(_3i_1);
            Compare<int, int> _4i_1_2 = new Compare<int, int>(_3i_2);
            Console.WriteLine("4i.1:\t" + Equate(_4i_1_1, _4i_1_2));

            // Test 5s (same type delegates from different static-methods with same IL compilations)
            Compare<int> _5s_1 = Test;
            Compare<int> _5s_2 = Test2;
            Console.WriteLine("5s:\t" + Equate(_5s_1, _5s_2));

            // Test 5i (same type delegates from different instance-methods with same IL compilations)
            Program _5i_0 = new Program();
            Compare<int> _5i_1 = _5i_0.Test3;
            Compare<int> _5i_2 = _5i_0.Test4;
            Console.WriteLine("5i:\t" + Equate(_5i_1, _5i_2));

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int Test(int l, int r) { return 0; }
        public static int Test2(int l, int r) { return 0; }
        public int Test3(int l, int r) { return 0; }
        public int Test4(int l, int r) { return 0; }

        // FIX ME!-----------------------------------------------------
        public static bool Equate(System.Delegate a, System.Delegate b)
        {
            // standard equality
            if (a == b)
                return true;

            // null
            if (a == null || b == null)
                return false;

            // compiled method body
            if (a.Target != b.Target)
                return false;
            byte[] a_body = a.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
            byte[] b_body = b.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
            if (a_body.Length != b_body.Length)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < a_body.Length; i++)
            {
                if (a_body[i] != b_body[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the tests that are currently failing:
2s, 2i, 4s, 4i, 4s.1, 4i.1

Comment: I would question why you would do this, but that said: So what doesn't work about the code you posted?

Comment: I thought it was obvious :P but I need it to write "True" for every test.

Comment: It would help if you said which ones failed with us having to compile and run it separately.

Comment: Done... Yeah I should have done that from the start...

Comment: The quick answer is that some of your delegates are actually pointing to other delegates. For example, the 2s cases `_2s_1`'s target is `_1s_1` and `_2s_2`'s target is `_1s_2`, not the targets the _1s delegates are pointing to.

Comment: omg you are right! So just infinitely traverse the targets until the target is not a delegate. That solved it. I will post the answer in just a minute

Comment: Why are you even creating delegates that point to other delegates in the first place?  Just don't do that.  It's just needlessly complicating the code and making everything harder to work with for everyone involved.  And of course there are millions of other ways of writing methods that are functionally equivalent, but that won't be considered equal by this algorithm.  The problem, in the general case, of determining if two snippets of code always produce the same result is (famously) provably impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to these test cases. You have to remove all the overhead of cause by the delegate assignments. Just continually check if the target is a delegate.

```
public static bool Equate(System.Delegate a, System.Delegate b)
{
    // ADDED THIS --------------
    // remove delegate overhead
    while (a.Target is Delegate)
        a = a.Target as Delegate;
    while (b.Target is Delegate)
        b = b.Target as Delegate;

    // standard equality
    if (a == b)
        return true;

    // null
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return false;

    // compiled method body
    if (a.Target != b.Target)
        return false;
    byte[] a_body = a.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
    byte[] b_body = b.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
    if (a_body.Length != b_body.Length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_body.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a_body[i] != b_body[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to make sure that you only yank out `Invoke` methods.  Otherwise if code tries to compare e.g. `(Action<Delegate>)delegate1.Combine` with `(Action<Delegate>)delegate1.Remove` such a comparison would devolve to a comparison of delegate1 with itself.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I will try to edit this post in the future sometime to add those test cases

Answer (score 0):

So let's pull out the first failing test case and look at it in isolation.  I'm going to change a few variable names for the sake of clarity.

```
Compare<int> firstComparer = Test;
Compare<int> secondComparer = Test;

Compare<int> thirdComparer = new Compare<int>(firstComparer);
Compare<int> fourthComparer = new Compare<int>(secondComparer);
Console.WriteLine("2s:\t" + Equate(thirdComparer, fourthComparer));
```

Now, when we get to the comparison, let's look at the target and method of each of these four delegates:

```
variable       | Target         | Method

firstComparer  | null           | Test
secondComparer | null           | Test
thirdComparer  | firstComparer  | Invoke
fourthComparer | secondComparer | Invoke
```

Now, technically, the `Target` of `thirdComparer` isn't the *variable* `firstComparer`, the target is the value of that variable; it's the delegate that `firstComparer` is pointing to when you evaluate `new Compare<int>(firstComparer)`, but hopefully you get the idea.

So why aren't the third and fourth delegates equal?  Because they have completely different targets.  These two delegates are both calling the same method of two different instances.  Now it happens to be the case that those two completely different instances are going to do the same thing when you invoke them, in this particular case, but that doesn't necessarily *need* to be the case.

So if you want your equality to support this you'd somehow need to be able to determine if the target of the various delegates point to the same variable *or point to equivalent values*.  Writing something that worked for this one case is probably doable; writing something that covered the general case is likely impossible.  You can't necessarily know, in the general case, whether two objects should be considered "equivalent".  You could pull out an `IEqualityComparer<T>.Default`, if that implementation would be sufficient.  It would probably work here, but not all types override equality in a way you might want it to.

The best solution is likely to avoid this problem in the first place.  Rather than having delegate's that, when invoked, invoke other delegates that are different, but that themselves point to the same value, you should just *remove that layer of indirection*.  If we adjust the test case above to:

```
Compare<int> firstComparer = Test;
Compare<int> secondComparer = Test;

Compare<int> thirdComparer = firstComparer;
Compare<int> fourthComparer = secondComparer;
Console.WriteLine("2s:\t" + Equate(thirdComparer, fourthComparer));
```

Then the test passes, because the third and fourth delegates are different from each other, but are the same delegates pointed to by `firstComparer` and `secondComparer`, which both have the same target and method.

All of your other test cases, and not just this one test case, have exactly the same problem, so I don't see a reason to look at each one individually.  All of them are adding this added layer of indirection, which is why they're not equal.

Comment: First off, I already found a solution :P I didn't realize that the constructor was just wrapping the delegates rather than copying the data from them. And assignment will NOT work for delegates of different types.

Comment: @ZacharyPatten You found a solution that special cases this one possible way that different methods can be functionally the same.  I could come up with another one that it doesn't support, and if you write something that special cased that, I could write another one, and so on, to infinity.  There will always be some way to have two delegates that, when invoked, will always do the same thing, but that you cannot prove are equivalent.

Comment: First off... You can always prove equality, but I'd rather traverse all the compiled IL function calls to determine equality. :P Secondly, I know that my "solution" isn't a fix-all, but it satisfies the purposes I intend to use it for. Thanks for your input though. :)

Comment: @ZacharyPatten No, you *can't*.  It's proven that you cannot prove that two methods will always provide the same results.  If you define equality as having the same target/method, then yes, you can test that, and these objects that you consider equal fail this test *as they should*.  If you define equality as "does the same thing" then you *can't* test that, in the general case.

Comment: We must be on two separate thought process here. I disagree that it is impossible in the general case. You could traverse all the IL and functions specific to the hardware in use. I would never do that... but it is certainly not impossible. I would like to see this "proof" so I know what definitions they/you are using.